# Font became BOLD and ITALIC in my clients computer

Tags: css, browser, fonts

Webpage is rendering the fonts in bold and Italic on my client's computer.

I did a careful research about the issue and I didn't find any problem on my code, nor html, nor css that can possibly be the cause of this problem.

The link is:
http://www.wrccdesign.com/connectors/digital-selling-program.html
The screenshot about the way it's rendering in his computer is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EW6JP.png)

I would like to know if anyone see the webpage with the same "bold and italic" font problem, like the image, and if anybody has faced a similar problem, What can possibly be happening?
Thank you!

Comment: This is not a solution, but an answer to your "does anyone see the webpage with the same 'bold and italic' font problem". I opened up your page and the font seems to look fine. (http://i.imgur.com/M1f1eVc.png)

Comment: Um, dude nobody can give you an actual solution if you don't give us any code.  Any solution I could give with no code would just be guessing and therefore would be completely useless to you.

Comment: Your HTML is full of warnings and errors. What a mess. https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wrccdesign.com%2Fconnectors%2Fdigital-selling-program.html Maybe use correct markup? If the quality of your html is an indicator of your CSS, then you might want to do something about your css as well.

Comment: Your CSS is okay.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the answers, I just had an answer from my client

> I resolved that issue.  It was local to my mac and the Roboto font
>   defaulting to Roboto italic/bold. Thanks"

So I guess its solved, so thank you very much all observations!